# how to avoid split and sum of pieces in pytorch or numpy

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I want to split a long vector into smaller unequal pieces, do a summation on each piece and gather the results into a new vector.
I need to do this in pytorch but I am also interested to see how this is done with numpy.

This can easily be accomplish by splitting the vector.

```
sizes = [3, 7, 5, 9]
X = torch.ones(sum(sizes))
Y = torch.tensor([s.sum() for s in torch.split(X, sizes)])
```

or with np.ones and np.split.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

## Edit:

Inspired by the first comment:

```
indices = np.cumsum([0]+sizes)[:-1]
Y = np.add.reduceat(X, indices.tolist())
```

solves it for numpy. I am still looking for a solution with pytorch.

Comment: Look for `numpy.reduceat`.

Comment: Great! this solves it for numpy. Thanks @Divakar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`index_add_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_) is your friend!

```
# inputs
sizes = torch.tensor([3, 7, 5, 9], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.ones(sizes.sum())
# prepare an index vector for summation (what elements of x are summed to each element of y)
ind = torch.zeros(sizes.sum(), dtype=torch.long)
ind[torch.cumsum(sizes, dim=0)[:-1]] = 1
ind = torch.cumsum(ind, dim=0)
# prepare the output
y = torch.zeros(len(sizes))
# do the actual summation
y.index_add_(0, ind, x)
```

Comment: a slightly more efficient way to generate `ind`: `ind = torch.arange(len(sizes)).repeat_interleave(sizes)`